# i got this AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'QuerySet'

Tags: python, django-models

```
class EntryQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

   def published(self):
     return self.filter(publish=True)

     class Entry(models.Model):
         title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
         body = models.TextField()
         slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
         publish = models.BooleanField(default=True)
         created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
         modified = models.DateTimefield(auto_now=True)

         objects = EntryQuerySet.as_manager()

         def __str__(self):
            return self.title

         class Meta:
                 verbose_name = "Blog Entry"
                 verbose_name_plural = "Blog Entries"
                 ordering = ["-created"]
```

plz tell me where error is occured?
and how to slove it?

Comment: Your `models` module doesn't expose anything called `QuerySet`.  You probably have a file called model.py in your code - does it have a QuerySet class defined?

Comment: this is for models.py code and i defined EntryQuerySet at the top of the class

Comment: You are probably using django 1.6, these features only work on django 1.7

Comment: oh!hmm thq got it Burhan

Answer (score 0):

Please see your views.py file and if you are using generic views , then your query will be written in the urls.py ,u might want to look at this for the detail explanation.

[class-based-views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/class-based-views/)